# Composition vs multiple singletons

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

I'm writing a desktop MMO game and I want to consult on the architecture question. I have such classes as NetworkManager, ClientWindow, CachingTextureAtlas they are needed only in one instance for the game and here is my question: is it correct to make them singletons? If yes it will be a kind of interaction through the global classes which is not good from the design point of view as it seems to me and if no we'll compose them in a facade and we'll have to pass those all to constructors of too many classes which is not convinient as well. What is a better choice?

Answer (score 5):

Singleton should be used carefully (almost never). I have seen many places, the recent sceanrio being hibernate session factory, where initially we thought that the single instance should be fine but then came across scenario for multiple instance and ended up refactoring the code.
Other problem is if you are writing unit tests for your code, then it will be a nightmare for all the classes which depends on these singleton classes.

One of the solution might be to inject a kind of factory which can provide you these instances/ it gives you a kind of indirection and avoid direct coupling. The other approach is to have a container (e.g. pico container) and inject as constructor dependencies which is what you have pointed out as well.

Comment: So you are against the singleton approach and what you suggest is to make a factory holding the instances of the classes needed? Or providing a new instance each time? I'm using Spring DI on the server side and I'll consider moving away from singletons there but what should we do with the client side where there is no point in Spring? And in the CachingTextureAtlas case it is very expensive to instantiate it each time, thanks ;)

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir I would prefer to go with Dependency injection. this abstracts the implementation from the methods calling it. hence you can change the implementation and most likely never have to refactor code.

Comment: Google Guice for client side? :)

Comment: With Spring DI, you can always say whether you want single instance or multiple instance(singleton vs protytype). Google guice or pico both are comparatively lightweight to spring.

Comment: Thank you Ankit I'll consider Pico :)

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir also be careful about the statefulness of your singletons, which is another big drawback besides coupling. If you regularly find yourself desperately debugging a singleton to trace back state modifications that have been made to it, it's probably that you need separate instances rather than a singleton. Making your singletons stateless and immutable right from the start will help you find out about their true nature much more quickly.

Comment: So as I understand it is always almost better to use DI/Factories?

Comment: yes I would say so. The only convincing reason I have found to use singleton till now is something like logging. Basically, if your almost every class need something and its universally singleton object then to avoid dependency in each class, you can use singleton object